# Does Microsoft Office Graph give a developer the ability to set permissions on the user level

Tags: office365

I have taken a dive in the deep end and started researching and fiddling with Microsoft Office Graph.  I am conflicted with the current documentation concerning permissions on the user level.  This is my following question.

1. Can I set permission on certain folders on the individual user level using Microsoft Office Graph api?

it seems that the permission are inherited from Sharepoint groups and Azure AD groups, but not explicitly given through Graph API to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph (previously called Office 365 unified API) exposes multiple APIs from Microsoft cloud services through a single REST API endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com). Using the Microsoft Graph, you can turn formerly difficult or complex queries into simple navigations.

The Microsoft Graph gives you:
•A unified API endpoint for accessing aggregated data from multiple Microsoft cloud services in a single response 
•Seamless navigation between entities and and the relationships among them 
•Access to intelligence and insights coming from the Microsoft cloud

And all this using a single authentication token.

You can use the API to access fixed entities like users, groups, mail, messages, calendars, tasks, and notes coming from services like Outlook, OneDrive, Azure Active Directory, Planner, OneNote and others. You can also obtain calculated relationships powered by the Office Graph (only for commercial users) like the list of users you are working with or the documents trending around you.

Why do you need to limit the resource by user-level? The user only can access the resource owned by her/himself by default.

But you can still write you own business logic in the application to limit the data service request by user-level.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use:

POST /drive/items/<id>/Microsoft.Graph.invite

to create a new permission with the roles you require for the users that you want to give access to item <id>?  The recipient should be able to be a user.  There's more information in the documentation at:

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem

(specifically the Create Permission and List Permissions sections).